# submit form loaded on the bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have dynamically created rows, on each rows i have a add button when user click on the add button then dynamically created form will be loaded on the bootstrap propover.
 [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aSZ6q/)

**my problem is :**

why  this code is NOT getting call? 
Basically i am Submitting  this form From bootstrap popover ?

```
 ...............
 ...............
console.log($("#"+formidd));// NOTE: i have accurate form id
         $("#"+formidd).validate({
            rules: {
                sproject_name: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    required: true
                }, tooltip_options: {
                    sproject_name: {placement: 'center', html: true, trigger: 'focus'}
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) { 
                alert("form submit");
            }
        });
     ...............
     ...............
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.Please help me...

---

**Form looks like this:**(I want to validate It & submit it when user press ENTER)
[image]

---

**My html data look like this:**

```
<div id="project-div-id"> 
        <ul style="padding: 0px 0 2px;margin-left: 0px;">
         <li><span class="slilink"> tour </span>
            <img class="del_btn" src="/images/icons/add.gif"> 
              <form action="http://localhost/task/index.php/mypage" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="160subproj" id="160subproj"  style="display:none;">
                  <input type="text" value="1st">
                   <input class="red-tooltip" data-trigger="focus" placeholder="add sub project" name="project_name" type="text" >   
              </form>
         </li>

         <li><span class="slilink"> personal</span>
            <img class="del_btn" src="/images/icons/add.gif"> 
              <form action="http://localhost/task/index.php/mypage" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="161subproj" id="161subproj"  style="display:none;">
                  <input type="text" value="2st">
                   <input class="red-tooltip" data-trigger="focus" placeholder="add sub project" name="project_name" type="text" >   
              </form>
         </li>

    <li><span class="slilink"> business</span>
            <img class="del_btn" src="/images/icons/add.gif"> 
              <form action="http://localhost/task/index.php/mypage" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="162subproj" id="162subproj"  style="display:none;">
                  <input type="text" value="3rd form">
                   <input class="red-tooltip" data-trigger="focus" placeholder="add sub project" name="project_name" type="text" >   
              </form>
         </li>
     </div>
```

---

**This is my FULL jquery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { var formidd='';

        $('.add_btn').popover({
            html: true,
             title: function () {
                 formidd=$(this).parent().find('.projform_id').html();
                return $(this).parent().find('.sub_proj_head').html(); 
            }, 
            content: function() { 
                return $(this).parent().find('.sub_proj_content').html();
            }

        });

        $('.add_btn').click(function(e) { 

             console.log($("#"+formidd));//i have loaded form id
         $("#"+formidd).validate({
            rules: {
                sproject_name: {
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    required: true
                }, tooltip_options: {
                    sproject_name: {placement: 'center', html: true, trigger: 'focus'}
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) { 
                alert("form submit");
            }
        });



            $('.add_btn').not(this).popover('hide');
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).click(function(e) {
            if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
                $('.add_btn').popover('hide');
            }  
        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: When you say "click enter", do you mean "press enter"?

Comment: @JamesM.Lay Yes i mean "press Enter".

Comment: SO NO-BODY THERE IN STACKOVER-FLOW TO ANSWER THIS QUESTION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do.  The enter button will not work by default unless you have an `<input type='submit' />` somewhere in the form.

Some hackery you can try is to place a submit button right after your input, give it a classname like "invisible", and set that class to remove all borders, margins, padding, etc...  Warning, setting `display:none` will not work because some browsers effectively remove the element.

For example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aSZ6q/1/)

**EDIT**: *I only got tour to work in the fiddle, but the idea is the same.  There has to be a submit input inside the form.*

Comment: Not helpful.. It is possible without submit button. Please try as i explain my problem above in this question.

Comment: My assumption is that bootstrap or jquery is invoking preventDefault() on the form.  I'll get back to you on this.

Comment: This is in fact the reason it is not submitting by default.  Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aSZ6q/23/) and run again removing lines 22 and 37.